# variable inside second for loop

Tags: xslt

I am trying to print variable value in second for loop of xslt but not getting displayed
here is my code

```
<xsl:for-each select="CampaignData/Mailer/CustomerInfo/CustInfFld/Coupons/Cust_Sel_Coupons">
                <xsl:sort select="@CouponPosition"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="CouponID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@CouponID"/>
                    </xsl:variable>

                        <xsl:for-each select="CampaignData/Mailer/Coupons/Cntr_Sel_Coupons">
                        <div style='color:red;'><xsl:value-of select='$CouponID'/></div>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Where is this $CouponID defined? This code doesn't tell anything by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `select` attribute of the nested `xsl:for-each` doesn't select anything and this is why its body isn't executed even once**.

Inside the inner `xsl:for-each` your current node is of the form:

```
CampaignData/Mailer/CustomerInfo/CustInfFld/Coupons/Cust_Sel_Coupons
```

The select attribute of the inner `xsl:for-each` specifies:

```
CampaignData/Mailer/Coupons/Cntr_Sel_Coupons
```

this is a *relative* XPath expression and it is resolved off the current node. Thus, the specified `select` for the inner `xsl:for-each` is actually (from outside of the outer `xsl:for-each`):

```
CampaignData/Mailer/CustomerInfo/CustInfFld/Coupons/Cust_Sel_Coupons
                                /CampaignData/Mailer/Coupons/Cntr_Sel_Coupons
```

It is highly unlikely there are any such nodes in the source XML document that you haven't shown.

Without having the source XML it isn't possible to say what exactly the relative expression should be -- most likely:

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select=
     "CampaignData/Mailer/Coupons/Cntr_Sel_Coupons">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select=
     "../../../../Coupons/Cntr_Sel_Coupons">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one potential problem is that the outer `for-each` changes the context node so the inner `for-each` needs to take that into account:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CampaignData/Mailer/CustomerInfo/CustInfFld/Coupons/Cust_Sel_Coupons">
    <xsl:sort select="@CouponPosition"/>
    <xsl:variable name="CouponID" select="@CouponID"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::CampaignData/Mailer/Coupons/Cntr_Sel_Coupons">
        <div style='color:red;'><xsl:value-of select='$CouponID'/></div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have also changed to code for the variable to simply write the expression you want to select in the select attribute instead of nesting a `value-of`.

If you still have problems then post a sample of the XML you want to process.